# My Console Application shuts down. What should I do?

Tags: c#, console-application

When I run my C# Console Application it opens and closes so fast that I can't even read what it wrote.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue... ");
Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Or use CTRL+F5...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

at the end of Main() function.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help